# Can I use DSN connections on Business Intelligence Design Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, business-intelligence

I was wondering if there is a way to use data sources for source/destination stored in system DSN (the "connections" you add on control panel by going to Administrative Tools -> ODBC Data Sources) in Business Intelligence Design Studio.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no way to do that. You can use configuration files or tables to manage what the connection managers actually connect to though.